# Remove 'custom-cpt' from 'custom-cpt/post-title' from custom post types permalinks

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

Lets say I have this custom post type: 'pt-services'

So, posts will have this kind of urls:

```
pt-services/post-one  
pt-services/post-two
```

How is it posible to remove `pt-services` from the urls? So they look like:

```
/post-one  
/post-two
```

I tried what suggested in [here](http://colorlabsproject.com/tutorials/remove-slugs-custom-post-type-url/) but didn't work...

Any thoughts?